# NSFetchedResultController and NSSortDescriptor with comparison block

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I've tried to implement an `NSFetchedResultController` giving it a `NSSortDescriptor` with comparison block, but it raises an exception saying that it doesn't support it.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"alarmTime" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate * obj1Date = [weakSelf returnClosestValidDate:(NSDate*) obj1];
        NSDate * obj2Date = [weakSelf returnClosestValidDate:(NSDate*) obj2];
        return [obj2Date compare:obj1Date];
    }];
```

I need to do that, because I'm sorting alarms that repeat in time and the property alarmTime is a date where there is the fire time and a date corresponding to the creation date. Since I need to show them in a cronological order with other alarms, if I do not correct the date the will always be on top (or bottom) of the list.
Is there a way to achieve this? I thought to resort them after but the sort descriptor is mandatory for a fetched controller.

Comment: I believe you cannot use a comparator block with a fetch, because it may be difficult to translate that to a SQL query. This is likely why it's "not supported". What is the type of "alarmTime"? If it's transient, that may also give you issues. Try leaving out the comparator block, and then sorting manually.

Comment: Hi @VasiliyDeych, thx for your suggestions. No, alarmTime is not transient is an NSDate attribute.